# Why does `apt-get -y install php8.0-dev` installs PHP 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, php

On my ubuntu 22.04, I used the PPA from `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php`

I ran `apt-get -y install php8.0-dev`, which required `php8.1-phpdbg` and it went ahead and installed PHP 8.1 which replaced my PHP 8.0

I find this behavior puzzling, any idea why `php8.0-dev` relies on `php8.1-phpdbg`?? Thank you!

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 17 2022 16:46:54) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the dependency is `php8.1-phpdbg` and it wants to upgrade `php8.0-dev` to PHP v8.1. After all the dependency is for PHP 8.1, so it probably installs PHP 8.1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with odd dependancies, might not be an ideal solution but you can run:
`apt-get install php8.0-dev --no-install-recommends`